# mongodb creates 80+ files 2GB each while database is empty

Tags: mongodb

**Background:**

I set the replicaSet and initiated 3 instances (1 arbiterOnly) of mongod on localhost using different ports.

I haven noticed that mongo is creating way too many files  in numbers and size which does not make sense at all.

See, **no data was ever** inserted into mongodb, not a single collection was created, and yet, letting it run for hour or so, and I have my /data/DB_INSTANCE_X full of 2GB files.

I am aware of the fact file's size can be defined with pre allocation flag, yet, so many files, before a single document was entered seems wrong to me.

Comment: Is it a brand new installation, or some databases did exist there in the past?

Comment: brand new, no databases, nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like it's preallocating space for the oplog. The oplog is allocated regardless of what you have inserted into the database http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space:

> The replication oplog is preallocated as a capped collection in the
>   local database.
>
> The default allocation is approximately 5% of disk space (64 bit
>   installations).
>
> If you would like a smaller oplog size use the --oplogSize [command
>   line parameter](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters).

Comment: So have you tried setting the oplog size with --oplogSize ? You say it seems wrong to you that there are so many files, but you haven't said if you've tried setting the oplog size manually.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/_iEeuzB8IK8 it is the oplog perhaps, yet this make no sense having 160GB of log generated with zero database insertion

Answer (score 0):

There are various command line parameters I have found to reduce the size of the empty database.

Already mentioned:

```
--oplogSize <value>
```

Also:

```
--smallfiles
--nssize <value>
```

The combination of all 3 parameters makes for an 18mb empty database (tested against MongoDB 64bit, Windows 7).

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/