# Why is MongoDB preallocating so many data files at once?

Tags: mongodb

Our MongoDB is currently sitting at about 1.2TB. We have 2TB total disk space on the server, and within one evening it created a few 2GB data files, using up all the disk space and crashing the process.

When I looked at the data files, I noticed that it preallocates a few of these files every couple of days, at one point generating more than 140GB of files.

How can I control this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb creates 80+ files 2GB each while database is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598971/mongodb-creates-80-files-2gb-each-while-database-is-empty)

Comment: @BlakesSeven No, the accepted answer there is an oplog issue, but I'm not using replica sets.

Comment: There are several answers there, and though the particular question uses a replica set ( so additional files ) the basic concepts of allocation and solutions are discussed there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to control the size of the generated data files you have the following options available to you when starting `mongod`:

- `--smallfiles` to decrease the initial data files size and limit it to a maximum of 512MB [[--smallfiles Manual Reference]](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--smallfiles)
- `--quota` and `--quotaFiles` to adjust the maximum number of data files allowed per MongoDB database 
  [[--quota Manual Reference]](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--quota)